# Batch merging shapefiles from different folders, different subfolders

Tags: arcpy, merge, batch

I tried some of the scripts I found but none worked so far.
What I am trying to do is batch merging hundreds, maybe thousands of shapefiles from different folders/sub-folders into a single shp or feature class (I read is better in case of large data).
My data is stored in [Shape Files] folder, as you may see here:

- O:\ABC\DEF\2010\project_nu\Shape Files*.shp
- O:\ABC\DEF\2011\project_nu\Shape Files*.shp
- O:\ABC\DEF\2012\project_nu\Shape Files*.shp
- O:\ABC\DEF\2013\project_nu\Shape Files*.shp
- O:\ABC\DEF\2014\project_nu\Shape Files*.shp

(where there's many project_nu in each year)

I don't have any experience in Python just in ModelBuilder.

I did a little bit of research and I understand that first I need to use the os.walk through all these folders and search for *.shp polygons (all shp's are polygon so there's no need to test this). Then apply merge to the generated list.

I tried ModelBuilder too (Iterate feature class-> Collect Values-> Merge) and got stuck in the iterative process that kept running with no results (I even tried for a few shps).

Comment: What software are you using?  What version?  (Please update the question).  Technically, shapefile names which are not "8.3" formatted are non-compliant.  Putting spaces in a shapefile name is a *big* no-no.

Comment: Simply use windows explorer, search for *.shp and add entire list (drag and drop) to Merge tool interface. Assuming you are using ArcGIS

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.1. I need a script cause I can't drag and drop thousands of shps spread in a lot of folders each month. It would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a list of many shapefiles using the glob module or os.walk, then you can use this list directly in the merge tool.

```
import arcpy, glob

yourlist = glob.glob(r"O:\ABC\DEF\*\project_nu\*.shp)
arcpy.Merge_management(yourlist, r"C:\output.shp")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with os.walk and fnmatch with very little code.  Try this:

```
import arcpy
import fnmatch, os

root = "whatever top directory here"
outdir = "wherever to output"
search = "*.shp"
outname = "whatever output name"

shpmerge = [] #This is simply an empty list to collect shapes.
for root, dir, files in os.walk(root):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, search):
        shpmerge.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

if shpmerge:
    outshp = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.basename(outname[0][:-4]) + "_Merge.shp")
    arcpy.Merge_management(shpmerge, outshp)
```

This is untested, but just some quick code - should work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 (or later) for Desktop I think you are better to look past `os.walk` and `glob` because [arcpy.da.Walk](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm) is more spatial data aware and can:

> Generate data names in a directory/database structure by walking the
>   tree top-down or bottom-up. Each directory/workspace yields a tuple of
>   three: directory path, directory names, and file names.